# Nunit -Check method was called with a parameter

Tags: c#, nunit

The test should test the AddDebug method works correctly. So If the username is null It will automatically set the user name to "Anononymus". However I can't see the List because it's private, therefore the only way to check to function works correctly is take advantage of that opportunity that the AddDebug method calling the Add method. I have to verify that the Add method was called with the "Anonymous" parameter
I only can use Nunit, Mock is not optional now for me.

```
private List<Log> Entries;
    public Logger()
    {
        Entries = new List<Log>();
    }
    public void Add(string text, LogLevels level, DateTime timeStamp, string userName)
    {
        var Enitity = new Log();
        Enitity.Text = text;
        Enitity.Level = level;
        Enitity.TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        Enitity.UserName = userName;
        Add(Enitity);

    }
    public void Add(Log log)
    {
        if (!(log.TimeStamp > DateTime.Now))
        {
            Entries.Add(log);
        }
    }
    public void AddDebug(string text, string userName = null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) == true)
        {
            Add(text, LogLevels.Debug, DateTime.Now, "Anonymus");
        }
        else
        {
            Add(text, LogLevels.Debug, DateTime.Now, userName);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You might use `Moq` library ti setup mocks for your methods and verify that it being called, but it requires using an interface

Comment: What this class do? Just saving logs to the private member which not being used by some other methods, makes this class useless. How this class is actually used, is there some methods which consumes `Entries` list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the facts:

- you cannot edit `Logger` class which is not unit test friendly
- the implementation does not expose `Entries` as public information, nor it could be passed into `Logger` as parameter
- none of the methods is virtual.

You have to use Reflection to get `Entries`.

```
var logger = new Logger();
logger.AddDebug("some text", userName: null);

// Get Entries in logger
var entriesField = typeof(Logger).GetField(
    "Entries", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var entries = (List<Log>)entriesField.GetValue(logger);
var containsAnonymous = entries.Any(e => e.UserName == "Anonymus");
```

However, this is usually / arguably not considered as a good practice in unit testing, as this relies on the internals of `Logger` class and it is likely that if you change the implementation of `Logger`, this unit test can break.

I would still recommend using one of @user8606929's solutions if it is possible.

Comment: Yes much more reasonable the Mock but this was the task. School things... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use a Mocking Framework like Moq.
See my attached example code.
ILog is the Interface for Log Class.

```cs
public interface ILog {
 void Add(Log log);
}
```

Your Logger class could look like this:

```cs
public class Logger : ILog{
....
public void Add(Log log)
   {
       if (!(log.TimeStamp > DateTime.Now))
        {
            Entries.Add(log);
        }
   }
}
...
```

You can design your TestCases like this

```
using Moq;

public class TestLogger 
{
  private Mock<ILog> _logMock;
  private ILog _logger;


  [Setup]
  public void SetUp()
  {

  _logMock = new Mock<ILog>();
  _logMock.Setup(a => a.Add(It.IsAny<Log>())).Verifiable(); // check if method is called

  _logger = _logMock.Object;          
  }

...

  [Test]
  public void SomeTest()
  {
   //test some business logik - inject your logger instance into businesslogic class

   //check if logger was called once
  _logMock.Verify(a => a.Add(It.IsAny<Log>()), Times.Once); 
  }

}
```

---

If its not possible to use Moq and external interfaces, you can write your test to check if your Entries List is not empty.

```cs
public class Logger
{
  public List<Log> Entries = new List<Log>();

  ...
}
```

```cs
[TestCaseSource(nameof(something))]
    public void AddDebugSetAnonymusUserTest()
    {
        var logger = new Logger();
        logger.AddDebug("Text", null);

       //here is the check if AddDebug was successful
       Assert.AreEqual(1, logger.Entries.Count);

       //check if user was anonymous
       Assert.AreEqual("Anonymous", logger.Entries.FirstOrDefault().UserName);
    }

....
```

Comment: Thank you! I can only use Nunit, because we haven't learnd Mock yet, and this will be part of my homework.

Comment: If it has solved your problem, I would be pleased if you would mark my answer as "accepted answer".  If not, please give me more information about your problem and the limitations.

Have a great day and happy coding/learning!

Comment: The problem is I can't add plus things like an interface, because the methods, and classes etc. was given. Mock is not optional for me. So my task is write the Nunit test for these methods.  I also have a BL.Test class and there is where I can write the tests.

Comment: i edited my answer above, pls check if this will solve your problem

Comment: Sadly It's not solved. The test should test the AddDebug method works correctly. So If the username is null It will automatically set the user name to "Anononymus". However I can't see the List, therefore the only way to check to function works correctly is 
take advantage of that opportunity that the AddDebug method calling the Add method. I have to verify that the Add method was called with the  "Anonymous" parameter

Comment: Can you edit your logger class?  The test would be successful if you set the Entries class to public or convert entries to a property. I have edited my answer again.
Notice that Log Entries List will now be a Property.

Comment: I can't modify the List to public. That is why i don't know how can do the test. I said the only way to check to function works correctly, leads through the Add method.